# javafx 8 edit text in textarea

Tags: javafx, textarea, stringbuilder

We are trying to correct the spelling of words in a TextArea
We have tried two methods onRemoveTwo failed with an IndexOutOfBoundsException
The other method onRemove works but it does a replaceAll we use replace in our code
Here are the results from both methods

Results from using onRemoveTwo
Initial text Take = Cariage NOT ME Carriag add missing voel to Carriage
Request was to correct **"Cariage"**
First correction results Take = Carriage NOT ME Carriag add missing voel to Carriage
With sb = sb.replace(from, to);
Request was to correct **"Carriag"**
Second correction results Take = Carriagee NOT MEg add missing voel to Carriage
We have this error Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
Caused by this line of code which we understand
while is finding two occurrence of the word
txaInput.replaceText(match.start(),match.end(),txtReplacementWord.getText());

Results from using onRemove
Initial text Take = Cariage NOT ME Carriag add missing voel to Carriage
Request was to correct **"Cariage"**
First correction results Take = Carriage NOT ME Carriag add missing voel to Carriage
Request was to correct **"Carriag"**
Second correction results Take = **Carriagee** NOT ME Carriage add missing voel to **Carriagee**
Notice both "Carriage" were changed to "Carriagee"

**So our question is how to be more specific about the word to be corrected?**

```
private void onRemoveTwo(){

    if(txtReplacementWord.getText().isEmpty()){
        txtMessage.setText("No Replacement Word");
        return;
    }
    cboMisspelledWord.getItems().remove(txtWordToReplace.getText());
    // Line Above Removes misspelled word from cboSelect 
    // ==================================================

    String text = txaInput.getText();
    String wordToFind = txtWordToReplace.getText();
    Pattern word = Pattern.compile(wordToFind);
    Matcher match = word.matcher(text);

    while(match.find()){

    ///System.out.println("Found "+word+" "+ match.start() +" - "+ (match.end()-1));

    String from = word.toString();
    String to = txtReplacementWord.getText();
    String sb = txaInput.getText();
    sb = sb.replace(from, to);
    txaInput.replaceText(match.start(),match.end(),txtReplacementWord.getText());

    txtMessage.setText("");
    txtReplacementWord.setText("");
    txtWordToReplace.setText("");
    cboCorrectSpelling.getItems().clear(); 
    cboMisspelledWord.requestFocus();

    // Code above replaces misspelled word with correct spelling in TextArea
    // =====================================================================
    int SIZE = cboMisspelledWord.getItems().size();
    if(SIZE == 0){
        onCheckSpelling();
    }
    }
}
```

Workable method but changes multiple words

```
    @FXML
private void onReplace(){

    if(txtReplacementWord.getText().isEmpty()){
        txtMessage.setText("No Replacement Word");
        return;
    }

    cboMisspelledWord.getItems().remove(txtWordToReplace.getText());
    // Line Above Removes misspelled word from cboSelect 
    // ==================================================

    String from = txtWordToReplace.getText();
    String to = txtReplacementWord.getText();
    String sb = txaInput.getText();

    sb = sb.replace(from, to);
    //sb = sb.replaceAll(from,to);
    txaInput.setText("");
    txaInput.setText(sb);
    txtMessage.setText("");
    txtReplacementWord.setText("");
    txtWordToReplace.setText("");
    cboCorrectSpelling.getItems().clear(); 
    cboMisspelledWord.requestFocus();

    // Code above replaces misspelled word with correct spelling in TextArea
    // =====================================================================
    int SIZE = cboMisspelledWord.getItems().size();
    if(SIZE == 0){
        onCheckSpelling();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well @Grendel I have no idea why this question is voted down. I have been working on a similar project with a TextArea and liked your code and like you found it frustrating that the StringBuilder finds any occurrence of the characters. So here is an answer the code is not real neat you will need to clean it up. I was unhappy that I had to go to a String[] array then to a ArrayList will keep working on this issue
In spite of the down votes enjoy the code
Send the check to 90.83.140.38

```
@FXML
private void onReplace(){

    if(txtReplacementWord.getText().isEmpty()){
        txtMessage.setText("No Replacement Word");
        return;
    }

    cboMisspelledWord.getItems().remove(txtWordToReplace.getText());
    // Line Above Removes misspelled word from cboMisspelledWord 
    // ==========================================================
    String line = txaInput.getText();
    oneA = line.split("\\s");
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(oneA));

        int theIndex = list.indexOf(txtWordToReplace.getText());
        String gotME = list.get(theIndex);
        list.remove(theIndex);
        list.add(theIndex,txtReplacementWord.getText());
        sb = new StringBuilder(); 
    for (String addWord : list) {
        sb.append(addWord);
        sb.append(" ");
    }
    txaInput.setText(sb.toString()); 
    txtMessage.setText("");
    txtReplacementWord.setText("");
    txtWordToReplace.setText("");
    cboCorrectSpelling.getItems().clear(); 
    cboMisspelledWord.requestFocus();
    // Code above replaces misspelled word with correct spelling in TextArea
    // =====================================================================
    if(cboMisspelledWord.getItems().isEmpty()){
        onCheckSpelling();
    } 
}
```

Comment: In the answer above by @James_Duh this line of code oneA = line.split("\\s"); should be oneA = line.split(" "); OR you loose your formatting in the TextArea it will strip out the "\n"